# React Hook: Pass one value from custom react hook to another react custom hook?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out how custom hooks are working. I want to get the person ID from one custom hook and pass the ID to a custom hook to get the user details. Is this working?
The user detail hook is always executed first and because of this it is not working.

```
App.js
 const username = props.navigation.getParam('username');
    const id = usePersonId('username');
    const userInfo = useUserInfo(id);

usePersonId
export default (username) => {
    const [personId, setPersonId] = useState(0);
    useEffect(async () => {

        let token = await new keys().getToken();
        let x = await new userService().getPersonId(token, username);
        setPersonId(x.user_id);

        return () => {
            console.log("cleaned up");
        };
    }, [])
    return  personId;
}

useUserInfo
export default (id) => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState('');
    useEffect(async () => {
        let token = await new keys().getToken();
        let x = await new userDetails().getUserInfo(token, id);
        const info = {
            "picture": pictureUrl,
        };
        setUserInfo(info);
        return () => {
            console.log("cleaned up");
        };
    }, [])
    return userInfo;
```

Thanks, 
Jan

Comment: Callbacks passed to useEffect should not be async themselves. But you can use declare and use async functions within them. Also both useEffect hooks have an empty dependency array `[]`. That means that they will never get triggered to rerun when things are changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I would need to add something in the brackets? I tried it with x in useUserInfo which led to a dead loop. When I add the ID to the brackets nothing happens because the ID is changing outside of this. Can I add something in the assigning itself as a reference?

Comment: Check out: [the hooks docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and this article [how to fetch data with react hooks](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data).  They should help you solve it.

Comment: Working now. Thanks a lot, this link and some thinking helped